# Trying to add html to my WordPress site, and it does NOTHING

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins, imagemap, gutenberg-blocks

I used Image Map Pro to map an image and add links. I used an HTML block (Gutenberg) to add the first snippet of code to my page. Furthermore, I used the WP Code plugin to add the second and third snippets to the body. Nothing. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried messaging Image Map Pro, posting on the WordPress forums, and asking on Facebook and Reddit, no help lol.

[The code provided by Image Map Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHUGj.jpg)

[Pasting the second and third code snippets into the body of my site, using WP Code plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U2WA.jpg)

[Adding the first snippet of code into my website page where I want the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR82k.jpg)

[The end result: absolutely nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcf7Y.jpg)

The end result should be an image of a clothesline with three clickable links embedded. Instead, it shows absolutely nothing.

The code provided by Image Map Pro is:

```html
<div id="image-map-pro"></div>

<script src="image-map-pro.min.js"></script>

<script>ImageMapPro.init('#image-map-pro', {"id":"cefca7b6-34bd-42ff-a9ff-acd4ecd75990","general":{"name":"Clothesline"},"artboards":[{"background_type":"image","image_url":"https://howthecrowflies.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/the-clothesline.png","children":[{"id":"5d6ed4f3-5656-4cfb-b76e-13dc9f0a15ed","title":"Poly","type":"poly","x":65.70121951219512,"y":16.20061610772358,"width":13.262195121951223,"height":16.966463414634145,"default_style":{"opacity":0},"mouseover_style":{"opacity":0.15540540540540543},"tooltip_style":{"background_color":"#82936a"},"tooltip_content":[{"type":"Heading","text":"REVIEWS","heading":"h3","other":{"id":"","classes":"","css":""},"style":{"fontFamily":"sans-serif","fontSize":20.8,"lineHeight":"normal","color":"#ffffff","textAlign":"center"},"boxModel":{"width":"auto","height":"auto","margin":{"top":0,"bottom":0,"left":0,"right":0},"padding":{"top":10,"bottom":10,"left":10,"right":10}},"id":"dff7359e-de06-465e-b81a-7b14fc81c823"}],"x_image_background":65.70121951219512,"y_image_background":16.20061610772358,"points":[{"x":0,"y":87.3015873015873},{"x":1.1494252873563218,"y":15.873015873015872},{"x":82.75862068965517,"y":0},{"x":90.80459770114942,"y":25.396825396825395},{"x":100,"y":73.01587301587301},{"x":20.689655172413794,"y":100}]},{"id":"110b3c2d-a352-4743-b69c-5cef7271659b","title":"Poly","type":"poly","x":34.29878048780488,"y":19.70163236788618,"width":27.59146341463414,"height":66.25,"default_style":{"opacity":0},"mouseover_style":{"opacity":0.15540540540540543},"tooltip_style":{"background_color":"#f89c6f"},"tooltip_content":[{"type":"Heading","text":"TRAVEL","heading":"h3","other":{"id":"","classes":"","css":""},"style":{"fontFamily":"sans-serif","fontSize":20.8,"lineHeight":"normal","color":"#ffffff","textAlign":"center"},"boxModel":{"width":"auto","height":"auto","margin":{"top":0,"bottom":0,"left":0,"right":0},"padding":{"top":10,"bottom":10,"left":10,"right":10}},"id":"e7742297-a907-4e7d-ad83-eeff5959124a"}],"x_image_background":34.29878048780488,"y_image_background":19.70163236788618,"points":[{"x":8.83977900552486,"y":53.65853658536586},{"x":3.867403314917127,"y":49.59349593495935},{"x":0,"y":43.90243902439025},{"x":0.5524861878453038,"y":38.61788617886179},{"x":1.1049723756906076,"y":30.48780487804878},{"x":3.314917127071823,"y":25.203252032520325},{"x":3.867403314917127,"y":19.10569105691057},{"x":5.524861878453039,"y":13.008130081300814},{"x":7.18232044198895,"y":7.317073170731707},{"x":9.94475138121547,"y":2.4390243902439024},{"x":16.574585635359114,"y":1.2195121951219512},{"x":24.30939226519337,"y":1.2195121951219512},{"x":32.59668508287293,"y":2.0325203252032518},{"x":36.46408839779006,"y":2.4390243902439024},{"x":45.30386740331492,"y":2.4390243902439024},{"x":51.38121546961326,"y":2.0325203252032518},{"x":57.4585635359116,"y":2.0325203252032518},{"x":64.64088397790056,"y":1.2195121951219512},{"x":72.92817679558011,"y":1.2195121951219512},{"x":79.55801104972376,"y":0},{"x":87.29281767955801,"y":0.8130081300813009},{"x":93.92265193370166,"y":1.2195121951219512},{"x":94.47513812154696,"y":6.910569105691057},{"x":95.02762430939227,"y":12.195121951219512},{"x":98.34254143646409,"y":16.666666666666664},{"x":97.79005524861878,"y":21.544715447154474},{"x":97.23756906077348,"y":25.609756097560975},{"x":98.34254143646409,"y":30.48780487804878},{"x":97.79005524861878,"y":35.77235772357724},{"x":98.89502762430939,"y":39.83739837398374},{"x":100,"y":45.52845528455284},{"x":99.4475138121547,"y":50.40650406504065},{"x":98.34254143646409,"y":54.87804878048781},{"x":95.02762430939227,"y":58.13008130081301},{"x":91.71270718232044,"y":61.78861788617886},{"x":88.39779005524862,"y":65.04065040650406},{"x":84.5303867403315,"y":67.47967479674797},{"x":82.87292817679558,"y":70.32520325203252},{"x":83.42541436464089,"y":76.82926829268293},{"x":83.42541436464089,"y":81.70731707317073},{"x":80.11049723756905,"y":88.21138211382113},{"x":72.92817679558011,"y":94.3089430894309},{"x":65.74585635359117,"y":97.96747967479675},{"x":56.9060773480663,"y":100},{"x":49.72375690607735,"y":98.78048780487805},{"x":43.0939226519337,"y":96.34146341463415},{"x":39.226519337016576,"y":91.869918699187},{"x":39.226519337016576,"y":87.39837398373984},{"x":39.77900552486188,"y":83.33333333333334},{"x":39.77900552486188,"y":78.86178861788618},{"x":40.88397790055249,"y":75.20325203252033},{"x":40.88397790055249,"y":69.91869918699187},{"x":41.988950276243095,"y":66.66666666666666},{"x":40.331491712707184,"y":63.82113821138211},{"x":39.77900552486188,"y":59.34959349593496},{"x":40.88397790055249,"y":56.50406504065041},{"x":39.226519337016576,"y":53.2520325203252},{"x":38.12154696132597,"y":47.96747967479675},{"x":36.46408839779006,"y":44.71544715447154},{"x":30.386740331491712,"y":44.71544715447154},{"x":24.861878453038674,"y":45.1219512195122},{"x":16.022099447513813,"y":47.15447154471545},{"x":10.497237569060774,"y":48.3739837398374}]},{"id":"e70c765c-d5f9-4a7e-975c-d3cec636cf53","title":"Poly","type":"poly","x":5.0304878048780495,"y":14.854071392276422,"width":16.768292682926827,"height":42.82012195121951,"default_style":{"opacity":0},"mouseover_style":{"opacity":0.15540540540540543},"tooltip_style":{"background_color":"#618483"},"tooltip_content":[{"type":"Heading","text":"BLOG","heading":"h3","other":{"id":"","classes":"","css":""},"style":{"fontFamily":"sans-serif","fontSize":20.8,"lineHeight":"normal","color":"#ffffff","textAlign":"center"},"boxModel":{"width":"auto","height":"auto","margin":{"top":0,"bottom":0,"left":0,"right":0},"padding":{"top":10,"bottom":10,"left":10,"right":10}},"id":"574d3efd-0e22-46d7-b12d-adffa374953f"}],"x_image_background":5.0304878048780495,"y_image_background":14.854071392276422,"points":[{"x":7.2727272727272725,"y":89.937106918239},{"x":0,"y":83.01886792452831},{"x":0.9090909090909091,"y":71.0691823899371},{"x":2.727272727272727,"y":61.0062893081761},{"x":5.454545454545454,"y":49.685534591194966},{"x":11.818181818181818,"y":47.16981132075472},{"x":15.454545454545453,"y":35.84905660377358},{"x":20,"y":25.78616352201258},{"x":25.454545454545453,"y":12.578616352201259},{"x":29.09090909090909,"y":3.7735849056603774},{"x":37.27272727272727,"y":0},{"x":48.18181818181818,"y":2.515723270440252},{"x":51.81818181818182,"y":8.80503144654088},{"x":51.81818181818182,"y":16.352201257861633},{"x":69.0909090909091,"y":19.49685534591195},{"x":73.63636363636363,"y":13.836477987421384},{"x":76.36363636363637,"y":5.660377358490567},{"x":89.0909090909091,"y":6.918238993710692},{"x":90.9090909090909,"y":15.09433962264151},{"x":89.0909090909091,"y":23.270440251572328},{"x":88.18181818181819,"y":33.33333333333333},{"x":91.81818181818183,"y":40.25157232704403},{"x":94.54545454545455,"y":49.685534591194966},{"x":97.27272727272728,"y":59.11949685534591},{"x":100,"y":69.81132075471697},{"x":94.54545454545455,"y":80.50314465408806},{"x":89.0909090909091,"y":90.56603773584906},{"x":80.9090909090909,"y":98.11320754716981},{"x":73.63636363636363,"y":99.37106918238993},{"x":61.81818181818181,"y":100},{"x":36.36363636363637,"y":99.37106918238993},{"x":17.272727272727273,"y":95.59748427672956},{"x":15.454545454545453,"y":89.937106918239}]}]}],"version":"6.0.5"})</script>
```

Comment: There's an old [Image Map Pro](There's a WordPress plugin (an old one) for Image Map Pro.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-map-pro-lite/) plugin you might try. Also, try previewing your post. And, open up your devtools and look at the console log and the Network tab as you load your preview. You may see some errors. Don't hesitate to [edit] your question to show us more information if you discover any.

Answer (score 0):

In your first image, it says that

```
<script src="image-map-pro.min.js"></script>
```

needs to be put just before the **closing** body tags, and then you are supposed to put the script code after it. However, your code snippets plugin says that the scripts will be printed right below the **opening** body tags. While I do know a little web development, it's not my first language, so that may have no effect on the situation.

My other possible solution would be to add the script directly into the HTML block. I'm not sure whether the div would need to go first or the script, but I do know that scripts can go in code blocks.